# pygeolib.GeocoderError: Error REQUEST_DENIED

Tags: python-3.x

I run the following code and expect the city and country name using latitude and longitude
*Here Is code .......*

```
from pygeocoder import Geocoder
result = Geocoder.reverse_geocode(22.8176662,70.8345928)
print(result.coordinates)
```

And Here Is the Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    result = Geocoder.reverse_geocode(22.8176662,70.8345928)
  File "C:\Users\Shyam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pygeocoder.py", line 165, in reverse_geocode
    return GeocoderResult(Geocoder.get_data(params=params))
  File "C:\Users\Shyam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pygeocoder.py", line 212, in get_data
    raise GeocoderError(response_json['status'], response.url)
pygeolib.GeocoderError: Error REQUEST_DENIED
Query: https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=22.817666%2C70.834593&sensor=false&bounds=&region=&language=
```